# Windows 7 Embedded - Disable Disk Caching Programmatically:

Tags: c++, wmi, windows-embedded, device-manager

**Preface:**

We are using a `Windows-7-Embedded` image, for making client-ready copies of our software.

The flow is pretty standard:

1. Take a blank hard-drive.
2. Restore an in-house `Windows-7-Embedded` image on the hard-drive.
3. Install additional software on-top.
4. **Hard-drive ready!**

**The Problem:**

Sometimes, probably due to system crashes, some configurations that are already configured inside the image - **reset.**

***My current problem is with a 'Disable Write Caching' option on the disk.***
In the image, the option is **off**.
Sometimes, it just resets and turns **on**.

**My Question:**

How can I programmatically disable the disk write caching property?

**Design Restrictions:**

- Can run an .exe on startup. The system is mostly c++ so that is that would be the optimal language for a code based solution.
- Can run a .bat file.
- can run a .vbs file. Not sure which version our current infrastructure are compatible with.

**Images (Inside Image -> After Crash):**

[image: The Disk Write Caching Option Off]
[image: The Disk Write Caching Option On]

**Clarifications:**

- Did my research. did not find anything related to windows write caching option in SO or SE as a whole. Did find a bunch of linux related questions.
- The system crashes are by-design, at the moment. This is the obvious root cause, but cannot be fixed due to design restrictions and budget issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry setting **EnableCache** you may try to experiment with. It applies to FAT file systems and setting it to 0 shall theoretically disable disk caching. Though I have not tested it.

Look into:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\StorageManager\FATFS** or **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\StorageManager\EXFAT**